# High Voltage error: undefined method `layout' for HighVoltage::PagesController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, high-voltage

I'm using ruby 2.1.2 and rails 4.1.1.

When I launch my app with 'rails s' I get no error in the terminal but when i enter in a web address for any page of the site, the terminal throws up this error:

```
undefined method `layout' for HighVoltage::PagesController:Class
```

Any ideas what i might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This means your `ApplicationController` isn't inheriting from `ActionController::Base` (for instance if you are using Rails::API and inheriting from `ActionController::API`).

If you want to leave the parent class of `ApplicationController` unchanged, one workaround is to make your own `PagesController`:

```
# app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ActionController::Base
  include HighVoltage::StaticPage
end

# config/routes.rb
get 'pages/home', to: 'pages#show', id: 'home'
```